# More tolerance needed for low quality questions during COVID-19?

Tags: discussion

As a college teacher myself, I tend to rapidly downvote and vote to close homework-style questions of the sort that the poster should answer themselves, perhaps by reading their textbook and/or asking their professor. But now, huge numbers of beginning computer science students have found themselves cut off from useful interaction with their professor and in many cases physical access to their textbooks (many students in the United States went away for spring break only to not return to their dorm which contains the book. Publishing companies have made e-copies of textbooks available, but it isn't quite the same).

COVID-19 doesn't excuse laziness on the part of the students, but it does constitute extenuating circumstances for a certain amount of cluelessness. I can observe many of my own students in the lower-level classes that I am currently teaching online ever since spring break struggling now, and it is the weaker students who are struggling the most.

Even if lower-quality questions should still be closed as readily as they have been in the past, I urge established users to be a little more gentle in their comments and a little more restrained in their downvotes.

Comment: Please not! the SE company is already doing enough to encourage *low* quality questions ...

Comment: by the way, tell your student to go to: https://www.pluralsight.com/ they are offering Free course during this period. This will probably reduce their questions here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't really disagree with you, but mostly asked the question so I could make people aware of the issue. I don't care about the downvotes (to this question, which I anticipated would garner mostly downvotes), but hope that those downvoting might at least take its last paragraph to heart.

Comment: we are already aware about all the low quality questions increasing each day and we need to be closing and downvoting more (not the opposite). We should not tolerate low questions, we should *teach* the new users (using our votes) how this site should work

Comment: Restraint on comments is always a good idea. Restraint on votes, not so much.

Comment: I find that we actually need to keep an better eye open for bad questions. I check the tags list for tags containing "corona" or "covid" every now and then to clean them up...

Comment: @yivi I don't disagree that downvotes are still warranted, but if such a question already has a couple of downvotes and comments which explain the problem with the question, some restraint on even more downvotes might be reasonable, especially for new contributors. Close the question, but no need to pile it on.

Comment: During the Spanish flu I didn't tolerate much either ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### We need curation more than ever.

Stack Overflow is an important asset for developers around the globe. Some of us are even losing their jobs, thus being forced to begin a new line of software development, potentially with unfamiliar technologies.

By not downvoting and/or voting to close poor questions, we are compromising the usefulness of this asset, making software development in general worse. No one wants that, much less in a crisis such as this one.

Comment: Nice answer. As a professor, I tend to have an academic-centered view of Stack Overflow, but you are right that developers are the primary target for it.